# Chrome extension error with getSelection and chrome.tabs.create

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

manifest.js

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "version": "1.0",
    "name": "Gramotey",
    "content_scripts":[
        {
         "matches":["<all_urls>"],
         "js":["main.js"]
        }
    ],
    "background":
    {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "commands": {
        "search_with_gramota": {
          "suggested_key": {
            "default": "Alt+Shift+5",
            "mac": "Command+Shift+5"
          },
          "description": "Общий поиск на грамоте"
        }
      },
      "permissions": ["scripting", "activeTab", "tabs"],
      "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((command) =>
{
    if (command == "search_with_gramota")
    {
        chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tab) {
            chrome.scripting.executeScript(
                {
                target: {tabId: tab[0].id},
                function: () => {
                    function makeUrl(){
                    var sUrl = "https://gramota.ru/poisk?query="
                    var selected = getSelection().toString()
                    sUrl =  sUrl + selected
                    return sUrl
                    }
                        chrome.tabs.create({url: makeUrl()});
                },

            });   
        });
    };
});
```

Any time I try to execute the shortcut only the following message appears in the console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgNgV.png)

I expect this script to open a new tab with url including currently selected text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says `chrome.tabs` is undefined. This is because the function is injected by executeScript into the context of the content script in the tab, where [most of `chrome` namespace is not exposed](/a/40682156).

The solution is to return the value from the injected function and use it outside as the result of executeScript:

```js
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(async command => {
  const text = await getSelectedText();
  if (text) {
    chrome.tabs.create({
      url: 'https://example.com/foo?' + new URLSearchParams({query: text}),
    });
  }
});

async function getSelectedText() {
  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true });
  const [{ result }] = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    func: () => getSelection().toString(),
  }).catch(err => {
    // console.log(err);
  });
  return result;
}
```